# Using a SQL table instead of XML file for application parameters

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, visual-studio

All of our applications currently load a XML file located on the network using Datamembers/Datacontacts with DataContactSerializer. I think it would be safer and easier for us to use a SQL Table even though i would be losing my Type Safety.

I'm trying to figure out a way to reproduce my classes inside my SQL Table so that when i wanna get value of a parameter, I only have to do MyConfig.Property but I can't find a solution other than

1. Implement a Get/Set for every property/field
2. List item

B) Use the code below but everytime i wanna get a property, i would need to do the following : MyConfig[nameof(Property)].

**Old VB.NET Code**

```
<!-- language: vb -->

Public Sub CreateConfig()
        ConfigApplications = New ConfigurationApplications
        ConfigRBTK = New ConfigurationRBTK2
        ConfigRBRE = New ConfigurationRBRE2
        ConfigTC = New ConfigurationTC2
        ConfigTLS = New ConfigurationTLS2
        ConfigTQ = New ConfigurationTQ2
        ConfigSoustrait = New ConfigurationSoutrait

        Dim ser As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(AppConfig4))
        Dim Settings As New XmlWriterSettings
        Settings.Indent = True
        Dim W As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ConfigFile, Settings)
        ser.WriteObject(W, Me)
        W.Close()
    End Sub
```

**New C# Code**

```
public object this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        string fullName = typeof(MyConfig).GetField(propertyName).DeclaringType.FullName + "." + propertyName;
        using (Info_IndusContext conn = new Info_IndusContext())
        {
            return conn.AppConfig.Where(x => x.Param == fullName).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }

    }
    set
    {
        string fullName = typeof(MyConfig).GetField(propertyName).DeclaringType.FullName + "." + propertyName;
        using (Info_IndusContext conn = new Info_IndusContext())
        {
            conn.AppConfig.Where(x => x.Param == fullName).FirstOrDefault().Value = value.ToString();
            conn.SaveChanges();
        }

    }

}
```

**SQL Table Preview**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>MyConfig.DefaultColor</td> 
    <td>Red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>MyConfig.SiteA.Color</td> 
    <td>Blue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could reduce the get & set to 1 line each, with some shared code.  After that, how many properties do you actually have to maintain?  The system I'm working on has around 100 and there haven't been any complaints.

Comment: I'd say i have about 1000 parameters total. I was just thinking that it's a waste of time to have 1000 properties with the very same code in both Get and Set. So I was looking for a way to either have like a "base property" or at least share the code.

Comment: You could always to what VS does for properties and use a T4 template to autogenerate the code whenever the model changes.

Comment: Also, 1000 application configuration items?!?!?!?  That's a code smell to me.

Comment: Both codes aren't equivalent. The old version reads the whole thing at once and then you simply read/write settings from a memory object, while the new version reads and writes from the DB each time you access a setting. Why not read the whole table into memory at startup and just leave your current configuration object unchanged?

Comment: Because I feel this particular application would benefit more from LazyLoading than EagerLoading. If a parameter changes while the application runs, i don't have to either restart the application or re-read the entire database. And yes we have 1000 parameters because we have multiple plants with multiple machines that each have many settings.

Comment: Maybe i'm not doing what's standard? How do you guys manage a configuration in C#? Keep in mind I have to EagerLoad it and that we could eventually build an interface where people could change settings on the go.

Answer (score 1):

I have a complex state object that I serialize and deserialize with `DataContractSerializer` and I love it. Not sure you're really doing yourself any favors. You'll be bending over backwards and doing a lot of tedious detailed stuff that the serializer does.  What you might consider doing is serializing the data contract to a stream or string that you read and write to the db. I've found that to take advantages of both worlds.

My state object has a `ToString()` override that looks kinda like:

```
public override string ToString( )
{
  var serializer = new DataContractSerializer( this.GetType( ) );
  using ( var stream = new MemoryStream( ) )
  {
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings( );
    settings.Indent = true;
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create( stream, settings );
    {
      serializer.WriteObject( writer, this );
      writer.Flush( );
    }
    stream.Position = 0;
    var reader = new StreamReader( stream );
    return reader.ReadToEnd( );
  }
}
```

...which makes it trivial to put into an `nvarchar` parameter in SQL, and it also helps with diagnostic examination.

Comment: BTW - this isn't a config thing...it's a wholly roll-yer-own state object, which might be a lot more appropriate if you're letting changes occur at runtime.